# Does every Process have its own Page directory?

Tags: memory, memory-management, process, paging, page-tables

(In 2-Level Paging)

If so: 
Does every process have multiple Page Tables?

If not: 
How is it ensured that a process doesn't point to a Page Directory Entry from a different process?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the answer:

It depends on the implementation. But in most cases every process does have its own Page Directory.

Also, a Page Directory can reference up to 1024 Page Tables. (But usually doesn't need that many)

And one Page Table can have up to 1024 entries.